# Compare two table of two different access databases

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This question might be bit old but i'm not  getting right answer when i google it .

I have two access databases one is A and another one B . Both will have same table structures and column names definitely .I want to compare data in each table and produce the result that is different from the both

I have a primary key in each tables .

Is it possible in access.Will it be fast if i have to compare total of 20000 records on whole

Comment: This may help http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=12731&sid=448d3b33a74fa720e118d945c672b968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a select query that pulls data from another database file:

```
select *
from [;DATABASE=c:\my\file.accdb].MyTable
```

Thus you can do joins between tables in different files and compare them.